# Calculating transition probabilities Markov chains

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-process

suppose we have a markov process defined by $$P(X_{n+1} = 1+x_n | X_n = x_n) = \dfrac{0.5+x_n}{1+n}$$

Where $X_n = \sum_i^n Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are random variables taking values $0$ or $1$

I want to find the one-step transition probabilities $p_{ij} = P(X_{n+1} = j | X_n = i)$

I can see that for $j = i+1$ we have $$P(X_{n+1} = j | X_n = i) = \dfrac{0.5 + i}{1+n}$$ but I am not sure what the answer will be for $j = i$. The answer is listed as $$\dfrac{0.5+n-i}{1+n}$$ but cannot see how

Comment: What is $x_n$ in the definition?

Comment: @Jack edited with more info

Comment: Definition for $X_n$ is in the question, but what is $x_n$? Is it some known sequence?

Comment: @Jack No, I took it as the value that X_n takes.

Comment: $\frac{0.5+n-i}{n+1} = 1 - \frac{0.5+i}{n+1}$.  So, $p_{ij} \neq 0$ only for $j=i+1$ or $j=i$.  Is this consistent with the statement of the problem?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yes it is - I am just not sure how the value $\frac{0.5+n-i}{n+1}$ has come about intuitively.

Comment: I guess the fact that $Y_i$ is either $0$ or $1$ explains it... Anyway, you are given one of the two nonzero probabilities.  The other has to be the difference t o1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are clearly only two options: at step $n+1$, either $X_n$ is incremented by $1$, or it is not.

You have that the probability of incrementing (i.e. $i \neq j$) is
$$
\frac{0.5 + i}{1+n}
$$
Then the probability of no increment is 
$$
1 - \frac{0.5 + i}{1+n} = \frac{1+n}{1+n} - \frac{0.5 + i}{1+n} = \frac{0.5 + n - i}{1+n}
$$